# AHK script to Python script

Tags: python, autohotkey

I'd like  to transcribe this autohotkey script into a python script, but I really don't understand this loop on ahk, can someone help me please?

```
Loop, Read, %arquivo%
    {
        Loop, Parse, A_LoopReadLine, %A_Tab%
        {
            StringSplit, content, A_LoopReadLine, =
            IfEqual, content1, Full
                execFull := content2
            IfEqual, content1, Compensation
                execCompensation := content2
            IfEqual, content1, Decompensation
                execDecompensation := content2
            IfEqual, content1, Preprod
                execPreprod := 1
        }
```

Comment: it appears to be looping through an file, splitting the key from the value by using the tab char and then the equals sign, or something in that format then assigning values based on the inputs found. Keywords to look at in the docs are "file reading loop", "stringsplit" and "IfEqual". Is there a specific point in the loop that you do not understand? The first question I would have is does it work?

Answer (score 0):

The `Loop, Read` loop is used to read each line of a text file, with the `A_Loop_Readline` variable used to store that particular line of text. It's like `for line in file:` in python, where `line` is equivalent to `A_Loop_Readline`.

The `Loop, Parse` loop is similar, but is used to iterate each section of a string, in this case, split by tab characters. In python, this would look like `for var in string.split("\t"):`.

So essentially, this script reads each line, then for each line it repeats the code inside for as many times as there are tabs in that line. If you wanted this code in python, it would look like this:

```
for line in arquivo:
    for i in line.split("\t"):
        content = line.split("=")
        if content[0] == "Full":
            execFull = content[1]
        if content[0] == "Compensation":
            execCompensation = content[1]
        if content[0] == "Decompensation":
            execDecompensation = content[1]
        if content[0] == "Preprod":
            execPreprod = 1
```